# Syntax for supertype and subtype relatiomship between tables in Mysql

Tags: mysql, database-design

I have a user table with columns user_id, username and password.Also there are three kinds of users; buyers,sellers and brokers with profile info having common columns name, address, description etc.Further the sellers and buyers have columns introducer column.Also every user will have exactly one of the profiles buyer, seller or broker. I want to set up supertype and subtype relationship in mysql.What will be the syntax in mysql?Thanks in advance for answering.

Answer (score 0):

mysql does not have specific syntax for supertype/subtype relationships. You can have a table for each subtype, if needed, and then create a view with a union of the subtypes to achieve the supertype. You'll need to make sure the primary keys of the tables do not collide. There are different ways to achieve it depending on the data.

Answer (score 0):

Super type/subtype relationship is a regular one to one relationship, you can add type or role column to "super type" table or to use a special USER_ROLE table. Actually you have user roles instead of types and super types in this particular use case. Generalization is a object oriented programming concept and usually it does not make any sense for data modeling.

Comment: Can you please provide the syntax in mysql for this case.Thanks for answering

Comment: Please see any sample database e.g. http://www.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/sql/SampleDatabases.html